# How can I get the raphael element of a DOM object that is created using raphael?

Tags: raphael

With Raphael I can get the a reference to the DOM object of an element using the following code:

```
 element.node
```

How can I get the element that is linked to the DOM object? In other words the inverse of the function above (e.g. DOMobject.element).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A node created with RaphaelJS has a `raphaelid` property or something very close you can log in Chrome DevTools or similar.

Since you know this specific ID and you have a reference to the Raphael `Paper` instance as the `paper` variable for instance, you get the element with:

```
paper.getById(node.raphaelid)
```

Actually, this is quite undocumented. Only the `getById` method is documented in the [RaphaelJS documentation (Paper.getById section)](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.getById)

**Update for the comment about not being able to get raphaelid on the DOM element**

Please have a look at this [jsfiddle about getting raphaelid](http://jsfiddle.net/7xCFL/).

HTML

```
<div id="c"></div>
<div><code>rect.node.raphaelid</code> : <span id="i"></span></div>
<div><code>rect2.node.raphaelid</code> : <span id="i2"></span></div>
```

JS

```
var paper = Raphael(c,400,400);

var rect = paper.rect(100,100,200,200);
var rect2 = paper.rect(150,150,200,200);

i.textContent = rect.node.raphaelid;
i2.textContent = rect2.node.raphaelid;
```

Text result

> rect.node.raphaelid : 0
>
> rect2.node.raphaelid : 1

All this with version 2.1.0 of RaphaelJS

Comment: And how do I get the raphael id of the element that corresponds to the DOMobject when I only have the DOMobject details?

Comment: This raphael id is a prop of the DOMobject. I will check the exact name as soon as i have a pc

Comment: Checked: Raphael adds a `raphaelid` property to the DOM element, that you can use to get the Raphael element back from the `paper`.

Comment: Hm, I could not find the raphaelid property on the DOM element (although that makes sense). I'm using Raphaël 2.1.0